# how do you get a substring inside another text?

Tags: c#, string, substring

I have this text format:

```
name:
last name:
birthday:
years old:
parent:
school:
```

And i have next information..

```
name:name1
last name:lastname1
birthday:13/03/1991
years old:20
parent:fatherx
school:university x
```

How do I get:

```
name1
lastname1
13/03/1991
20
fatherx
university x
```

...for different variables?
dont forget user sometime they dont have a information for example they have empty

```
parent:
```

Comment: @Ed: There's a question there, it just got sucked into the code section.

Comment: Is the Info in a string variable?

Comment: dare i say it...regex match groups perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

`Split` on the colon.  For example, if you had each one of your lines stored in a seperate string, you could do the following e.g.

```
string s = "name:angel rodrigo";
string name= s.Split(':')[1];  // Get everything after the colon
```

Comment: what meaning[1]?? sometime user doesn't write a date for example they dont have a university does it work?

Comment: `1` will get everything after the character that you are specifying (in your given example).

Comment: It means every thing between the first `:` and the second `:` if there is a second one. if there is no second `:` it will be getting everything after the first `:` to the end of string. read more at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx)

Comment: And to answer the OPs question, if there is no value after the `:`, then, no, it won't work

Comment: You need to fail proof your code: 1. what is there's no :? 2. What if string is null?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to create a dictionary of key-value pairs.

```
     List<string> fields = new List<string>
     {
        "name:",
        "last name:",
        "birthday:",
        "years old:",
        "parent:",
        "school:",
     };
     string rawData =
        @"name:angel rodrigo
last name:uc ku
birthday:13/03/1991
years old:20
parent:fernando uc puc
school:university x";

     var data = 
        fields.ToDictionary(
           field => field.TrimEnd (':'),
           field => Regex.Match(rawData, "(?<=" + Regex.Escape(field) + ").*"));
     foreach (var kvp in data)
     {
        Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + "  =>  " + kvp.Value);
     }
```

Produces this result:

```
name  =>  angel rodrigo
last name  =>  uc ku
birthday  =>  13/03/1991
years old  =>  20
parent  =>  fernando uc puc
school  =>  university x
```